# How is anyone supposed to get their first job in IT networking or security?

Tags: job-search

I just graduated with two degrees in IT networking and security, I have a CCNA and a Security+, and I spent a few years working for my college to tutor other IT students, but every "entry level" job I see in either field has hard requirements for years of experience in those specific roles already. I've applied for over 40 of them where the experience requirements were on the lower end, because people have told me that those are often inflated. But whenever I've heard back from any of them, the feedback I keep getting is that I don't have the experience they're looking for.

I've run my resume and cover letter by a bunch of people who say it looks good, so I don't think that's it.

Some people have recommended headhunters, but as far as I can tell these days they're not much different from Monster or Glassdoor- they just take your information and spit out a bunch of related job postings and tell you to go for it. I also have a LinkedIn page that's completely filled out, but I'm just not really getting any offers except for a few low-level and low-paying help desk/tech support jobs.

So how does anyone actually get into any of these fields? I don't mind working at a help desk for a while, but my concern is that the track out of the help desk and into the networking or infosec departments is too long and I'm going to forget 75% of what I know during that time since I won't be using it, and also there's always a line of people ahead of me who want any openings in those departments as well so it seems like it will take forever (one interviewer told me, "Well, anything's *possible*" in regard to my chances of getting there within five years). So what am I missing here?

Comment: This is probably a very bad time to be searching for entry level roles right now, so it is possible you are missing nothing.

Comment: "*every "entry level" job I see in either field has hard requirements for years of experience in those specific roles already*" Those are by definition not entry level. You need to be looking for graduate roles which list 0 years of experience but of course this isn't the best time for that. What makes you think positions with 2+ years' experience requirements would be entry level?

Comment: If you admittedly do not have the necessary experience, why are you applying to positions that require experience?

Comment: "What makes you think positions with 2+ years' experience requirements would be entry level?" Because they describe them as "entry level" in the job description. And I agree, that's why I put it in quotes.

Comment: "You need to be looking for graduate roles which list 0 years of experience" "If you admittedly do not have the necessary experience, why are you applying to positions that require experience?" That's my point- there are no jobs that don't require experience in networking or security despite having the academic training for them. So how does anyone get into the field in the first place?

Comment: Just gotta get your foot in the door and prove yourself, additionally get to know the people above you. My first job and current job started at $15 an hour, but I was able to prove myself and my worth as a developer. Four years later, I make triple that. Sometimes the job that does not pay as much as you think you should be paid is the way, and if your prospects do not change within that job, move on. You got the experience. Unfortunately, your education does not prove how good you are. Therefore, you must take the **true** entry level job.

Comment: "Sometimes the job that does not pay as much as you think you should be paid is the way, and if your prospects do not change within that job, move on. You got the experience." This still doesn't address the point though- the networking and security jobs I've seen all require experience in those specific roles. Taking some other low-level job presumably wouldn't accomplish that since they're not specifically networking/security jobs. So how do you "get your foot in the door" if you can't get a job in those roles in the first place without the prior experience?

Comment: @Grynn Correct me if I am wrong, but usually help desk/support IT people can easily transition into network admins or similar roles especially within a company. My company's support person (we are are small IT team, four of us) started off doing only support and as he proved himself more and more, his responsibilities increased.

Comment: @Alec I don't know, this is kind of what I'm asking. Since all the job listings I've seen require you to have already had a job in network/security, I assumed that applied to internal candidates as well. But maybe I'm wrong about that?

Comment: If you're not in the correct social caste to have parents fund you while you spend years on unpaid internships, there's no hope. Enjoy your minimum wage existence dreaming about when social mobility was a thing.

Comment: @Grynn I think you may be wrong about the internal candidates. Promoting from within has many benefits, including avoiding the training aspect of brand new hires. Plus the money spent on finding one as well can be saved by promoting the right person already in the company. Granted this person must show they are capable of the task, whether it be learning it quickly and already have the abilities needed.

Comment: @Grynn, many (if not most) jobs openings are filled through personal connections. Job boards where you submit your application on the web are a shot in the dark, especially for commodity or entry-level IT roles. Try, instead, to find alternative ways of reaching out to people in the industry. Contrary to what others say, ~1-2 years experience is effectively entry level. The vast majority of employers are willing to be flexible on most requirements if the candidate can convince them they're a good hire, but you can only do that if you're not first screened out by a dumb keyword filter.

Comment: To be fair, I don't know a lot about networking jobs nor about your country. But personnally, I applied probably to more than 200 roles and had so many interviews before getting any positive feedback. Just keep looking, and maybe lower your expectations a little. As a junior developer, you often need to start somewhere before getting to what you want to do.

Comment: Please don't delete the vast majority of content from your question; that's not helpful as it means that the answers not longer answer your question. Thanks!

Comment: @Grynn Try to arrange informational interviews with people who have the type of job you want or who work for the companies you want to work for. Ask them these questions. Then ask them who they know that you should interview next. Not only will you gain information, you will add people to your professional network that can eventually recommend you for an opening.

Answer (score 14):

> I'm just not really getting any offers except for a few low-level and
>   low-paying help desk/tech support jobs.

Those are the jobs you should be taking. That's how you get your foot in the door in the IT profession (and probably with any/every other professional career). Once you're in the door, you start building real world experience, skills, and knowledge. Then you work your way up the ladder, either at the same company or by applying for progressively more challenging and demanding positions at other companies.

You may have some training and education but nobody is going to hire you as a system or network administrator except at companies that aren't going to pay well for those positions and are looking for someone like you who will accept those positions and low pay because they know that's how they'll be able to break in.

I worked for a year as a help desk tech and then found a job posting for a company looking for a system/network administrator. The salary was half of what an experienced system/network administrator would normally earn. I took the job because I knew it was my opportunity to break into the position I really wanted. I worked at that company for 5 years, over which time I tripled my initial starting salary and earned the title Senior Systems/Network Administrator.

I haven't looked back since. 20 years on and I now work for myself, commanding an hourly rate commensurate with the best IT Consulting firms in my area.

Comment: But like I said, all of the job listings I've seen for network technicians/admins and for security jobs all require experience in those specific roles, not just any IT experience that could be fulfilled by a help desk job.

Comment: No, you said `I'm just not really getting any offers except for a few low-level and low-paying help desk/tech support jobs.` - Those are the jobs you should be taking, as I stated in my answer. You take a low-level, low-paying help desk/tech support job and you work your way up from there. After some time and experience you'll be better positioned to apply to those network technicians/admins and security jobs.

Comment: "No, you said I'm just not really getting any offers except for a few low-level and low-paying help desk/tech support jobs." Before that, in the first paragraph, I said, "...every "entry level" job I see in either field has hard requirements for years of experience in those specific roles already."

Comment: Let me see if I can clarify. 1. You are not getting offers for low level positions in networking and/or security. 2. You are getting offers for low level positions in help desk/tech support. If these statements are true then what I'm saying is that you should be taking those low level help desk/tech support jobs. Those will launch you into the IT career you really want. That's how it works. Every systems, network, or infosec engineer started on the help desk or in tech support. Nobody is going to hire you into those positions with no experience.

Comment: If you go to college to earn a degree in accounting you don't get a job as a company controller or CFO. You get a job as an accounts receivable/payable clerk. You work your way up from there. And so it goes in the IT field (and every other field). Take the help desk/tech support jobs and use them as your launching pad.

Comment: So are you saying then that the all the job listings I've seen for networking/security jobs that say they require you to have experience in other networking/security jobs are not accurate, and they would accept someone with exerpience in a help desk/tech support role? Otherwise I don't see how you can make the transition since you could be the best help desk tech on the planet but you still wouldn't have any experience as a network/security tech.

Comment: I'm saying that the help desk/tech support positions are where you're going to get the experience those other jobs are looking for. As a help desk/tech support role you're going to inevitably get involved in networking and security issues. Then you'll gain experience and knowledge in those areas. Then you'll get a promotion to a junior role in networking/security. Then you'll either get promoted higher or you'll get job offers for those positions at other companies. The bottom line is that you need to start somewhere, and help desk/tech support is where you'll start.

Comment: Ok, that's what I was asking. So to be clear, you're saying that despite the fact that companies will (according to what I've seen) only consider external candidates who have already held jobs as network or security technicians, they would promote someone from within even if they haven't already held those specific roles because they've seen them in action? I've been assuming that the requirements for external and internal candidates would be the same, so is that what I'm not understanding?

Comment: Of course it's different at every company, but in general, most companies are invested in and take an interest in the development and growth of their employees. If you show a desire and the aptitude to grow into ever more demanding roles, the company will usually work with you to help you achieve that. It's good for you and it's good for them. It's also usually cheaper for a company to promote from within then it is to hire externally. That's neither good nor bad, it's just what it is.

Comment: Ok, that's what I was asking. Thanks.

Comment: Good answer, the only fast track is a personal connection of some kind

Answer (score 6):

> So how does anyone actually get into any of these fields?

As with any field, you need to have the right background that an employer is seeking. And you need to get lucky.

> I'm just not really getting any offers except for a few low-level and
>   low-paying help desk/tech support jobs.

Sometimes you need to start in lower-level roles and work your way up to your desired position. When I was looking for lower-level workers for my teams, I often looked internally first. That often meant hiring someone from the Help Desk or Customer Support.

Answer (score 5):

I was in your position too early in my career 20 years ago.  That "Catch 22" of needing experience right out of school killed me in a major-metropolitan area.  I got the door slammed in my face countless times.  I even had some internship experience I thought I could bank on, which unfortunately didn't help.

I talked to many headhunters, and while they seem helpful at first, you have to realize they are only sales people trying to sell you, and not actually capable of giving you a job.

Eventually I got desperate, and took a technical job in a smaller town that didn't have the candidate pool a larger city would have.  I think we both were a little desperate.  While I only worked at that job 2-years, the experience I learned has been instrumental in each job I landed since.  Like the other answerer said, I can now command top dollar for my experience anywhere I choose.

Answer (score 3):

I honestly can't believe anyone in IT can't find a job right now. Every single company I know, both my own and all our customers, is looking for IT people.

**ignore** the requirements posted in the job description. Most of them are put there by HR people who know nothing about IT. Nobody expects you to satisfy them all, most will be happy if you satisfy around half. In fact, every single job I've had in my 30 year career had a few requirements that I didn't satisfy, and it never mattered.

**connect** to people in the field - sign up with industry organizations in your specific sub-field that organize regular meetings in your area. For me that was ISACA, for your area it might be something else. Check for the ones with reasonable yearly fees ($100 or so), not the golf-club-exclusive ones - those we set up to fleece the MBAs and rich kids.

**write** to companies that you are interested in, even if they don't currently post job offers. Several companies I know have simply given up on posting job offers and rely on word-of-mouth, job fairs or "recruit a friend" employee programs, because they tried finding people on the open job market for so long that they feel it's a waste of money.

**attend** university job fairs. That is where companies who are happy to hire someone with no job experience go to.

--

Another not strictly related advise: Experience doesn't have to be job experience. Have you contributed anything to a Free Software project? Do you have a github account with some projects you can show off? Count those things as experience, they matter.